# Value is out of range error when reading text from a shape

Tags: vba, excel

I need to output a text file with the specified shape name and the text inside of it.

The error I am getting is

> Run-Time Error '-2147024809(80070057)' The specified value is out of range.

```
Sub test()
Dim objFSO As Object, objFile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\[user]\Documents\text.txt", 2)
objFile.Write "" 'This clears the text file

Dim obj As Shape

For Each obj In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    sWrite = obj.Name & "; Content: " & obj.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text
    Debug.Print sWrite
    objFile.WriteLine sWrite
Next obj
objFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean *subscript* is out of range?

Comment: What is the exact error you get, and on which line?

Comment: `sWrite = obj.Name & "; Content: " & obj.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(0, 300)` Would bet this line is your issue. If you don't have 300 characters, you will get a subscript out of range error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. It's clear you need help, or you wouldn't be posting here, and it's clear you can't figure it out for the same reason. Removing that from your title leaves Excel VBA, both of which are available in your tags, and removing that leaves nothing. Your title should be clear enough so people know what the question is about, and descriptive enough for future readers here who see it in a list of search results. Posting noise in the title doesn't help future readers or you get help.

Comment: What does it mean "an object and the text inside of it"? What type of an object are we talking about? Apparently the problem is with the property `.TextFrame2` - MSDN says it contains text formatting of the specified shape. If are after e.g. what is the alternative text, use `obj.AlternativeText`.

Comment: Eleshar, i switched out the code with your segment and it doesnt return the error but it doesnt even give the text inside the shapes. the above code would return 4 lines of what i needed, but then error out. i am using this for a flowchart, and need to add interactivity down the line so im spelling out the shape names so i can have things show and disappear, sorry about the lack of phrasing things i dont use VBA at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code work fine in my pc

```
Sub test()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFile As Object' here is your problem

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\[user]\Documents\Proyect folder\otros\test & intentions\test.txt", 2)
objFile.Write "" 'This clears the text file

Dim obj As Shape

For Each obj In ActiveSheet.Shapes
  sWrite = obj.Name & "; Content: " &    obj.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
  Debug.Print sWrite
  objFile.WriteLine sWrite
Next obj
objFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: still returned the same error as before, and i copied and pasted the entire thing and just adjusted the references. thanks though. Actually i just figured it out, the 5th shape that it grabs was an arrow, which has no text, so when it got to it the script errored out